# My .desktop app runs from /tmp/ folder, how to set an icon for it?

Tags: icons, .desktop, desktop-icons, tmp

**How to change an icon for file that runs from /tmp/ folder?**

Run command: .home/*username*/apps/eDEX-UI-Linux-x86_64.AppImage/ *--disable-gpu-sandbox*

Running app command: /tmp/.mount_eDEX-U8YAX2V/edex-ui --type=gpu-process --field-trial-handle=1234567890,1234,1234 --enable-features=WebComponentsV0Enabled --disable-features=CertVerifierService,CookiesWithoutSameSiteMustBeSecure,SameSiteByDefaultCookies --disable-gpu-sandbox

Again: how to change running app icon?

*System info:*

Ubuntu 22.04 LTS,

Gnome 42,
24 GB Memory DDR3,

Nvidia GeForce GTX 1060 3GB,

Driver version 515.65.01.

.desktop file in ~/.local/share/applications

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=eDEX-UI1
Exec=/home/hideuk/apps/eDEX-UI-Linux-x86_64.AppImage --disable-gpu-sandbox
Comment=Terminal emulator
Terminal=false
Icon=/home/hideuk/.local/share/icons/edex.png
Type=Application
Hidden=true
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use the tmp directory? Read this info in regards to that. Whereas in /tmp, the data gets automatically deleted after ten days. Furthermore, any temporary files that are stored in the /tmp directory get removed immediately on system reboot. As such, the /var/tmp directory is used by programs to store data that needs to be preserved between reboots temporarily. Source page https://www.fosslinux.com/41739/linux-tmp-directory-everything-you-need-to-know.htm#:~:text=Whereas%20in%20%2Ftmp%2C%20the%20data,be%20preserved%20between%20reboots%20temporarily.

Comment: @David i just wanna set up an icon for it, it's a program runs itself from that folder.

Comment: Let me say again that folder gets cleared on each reboot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That the executable is located on a temporary drive does not matter here: this is how appimages work.

The icon shown for an app is set in the `.desktop` launcher of that application. Your `.desktop` launcher instructs that there is an icon in `Icon=/home/hideuk/.local/share/icons/edex.png`. If the file `edex.png` exists on that location and is a valid file, it will be used as the icon for the program. If you want to change the icon, then provide a valid path to the file you want to use instead. *Tip*: if you place the icon under `~/.local/share/icons` or `~/.icons`, it will be sufficient to specify only the file name without extension (`Icon=edex`).

If it doesn´t, then the desktop was unable to keep track of the created window. In that case, you may need to specify the window class of the running application, and indicate that in the `.desktop` launcher through a new line `StartupWMClass=<WMClass>`. Subsitute `<WMClass>` by the actual window class. To find the window class, run the application. Then find its window class in the "looking glass" of the desktop: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type `lg` the <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Find the wmclass on the "Windows" tab.

If you run on Xorg instead of Wayland (the default), you can also find the wmclass in the output of `xprop` or `wmctrl -lx`.

Comment: thank you, i'll try this out and reply.

Comment: thank you so much, that works for me!